# Problemas generando tabla dinámica con JQuery

Tags: jquery

Quiero crear una tabla de la siguiente manera:

- Por cada medida (seria un registro de la tabla medida), debe haber una fila.
- Además de la columna medida que tendría el nombre de la medida debo insertar un `combobox` con las canillas, es decir todas las medidas se relacionan con todas las canillas.
- Es un sistema de una cervecería por lo que se extrae cerveza de las canillas en distintas medidas.

Entonces hago:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "views/modules/medida/procesomedida.php",
    data:{"accion":"listar"},
    dataType:"json",
    error: function(){
        alert("error petición ajax");
    },
    success:function(data){
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            contenido='<tr><td style="width:100px;"><input type="number" min="1" class="col-sm-12"  /></td><td style="width:200px;">'+item.descripcion+'</td>';
            select='<td style="width:400px;"><select style="width:390px;"><option value="1">Seleccione</option></select></td></tr>';
            $(contenido).appendTo("#venta tbody");
        });
    }
});
```

Y obtengo las medidas.

Luego:

```
accion="listarcanilla";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "views/modules/envase/procesoenvase.php",
    data: { "accion": accion}, 
    dataType: "json",
    error: function(){
        alert("error petición ajax");
    },
    success: function(filtrado){
        opciones="";
        $.each(filtrado, function (index, i) {
            opcion="";
            opcion='<option value='+i.idcanilla+'>'+i.idcanilla + '  ' +i.nombre+'</option>';

            opciones=opciones + opcion;
            select=select + opciones;
        });
    }
});
```

Osea, hago otra petición `ajax` para las canillas, y se me ocurrió armar el `html` del `select` por cada canilla y unirlo al contenido, pero no funciona:

```
$(contenido).append(select);
$(select).append('</select></td>');
$(contenido).append('</tr>');
$(contenido).appendTo("#venta tbody");
```

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Así tengo el javascript actualmente:

```
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "views/modules/medida/procesomedida.php",
            data:{"accion":"listar"},
  dataType:"json",

        error: function(){
            alert("error petición ajax");
        },
        success:function(data)
        {


   $.each(data, function (index, item) {


     contenido='<tr><td style="width:100px;"><input type="number" min="1" class="col-sm-12"  /></td> '+
     '<td style="width:200px;">'+item.descripcion+'</td>';
      select='<td style="width:400px;"><select style="width:390px;"><option value="1">Seleccione</option>';
      accion="listarcanilla";
 $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "views/modules/envase/procesoenvase.php",
        data: { "accion": accion}, 
        dataType: "json",
        error: function(){
            alert("error petición ajax");
        },
        success: function(filtrado){
            opciones="";
          $.each(filtrado, function (index, i) {
        opcion="";
       opcion='<option value='+i.idcanilla+'>'+i.idcanilla + '  ' +i.nombre+'</option>';

      opciones=opciones + opcion;
  select=select + opciones;
        });
               }
            });

            console.log(select);
     $(contenido).append(select);    

   $(select).append('</select></td>');


 $(contenido).append('</tr>');
  $(contenido).appendTo("#venta tbody");

 });

  }
       });
```

Y este script está incluido dentro del html:

```
         <form class="form-horizontal">
<script src="views/modules/venta/indexventa.js"></script>
<p>NUEVA VENTA</p>
 <div class="form-group" id="grupo">
 <div class="row" id="fechacli">
   <div class="col-sm-1">
      <label>FECHA</label>
   </div>

   </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fecha"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <label>NOMBRE</label>
   </div><div><label id="nombre"></label></div>

 </div>

   <div class="row" id="cli"> 
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <label>CLIENTE</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codcli" 
      <?php if (isset($_POST['id'])){
        ?> value="<?php echo $_POST['id'];?>"<?php
      } ?>placeholder="Cliente"/>
      </div>


   <a id="cli" class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php?controller=venta&action=cliente">Buscar</a>
 </div>


<div class="row">
<table id='venta'>
<caption>Ingrese articulos</caption>
    <thead>
        <th>CANT.:</th>
        <th>MEDIDA:</th>
        <th>CANILLA:</th>
        <th>P/U:</th>
        <th>SUBTOTAL:</th>
        <th>PROMO:</th>
        <th>TOTAL:</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
    </table>

      </div>
```

Comment: ¿Las llamadas son consecutivas? ¿Podrías poner el código junto y el HTML de `#venta tbody` para facilitarnos un entorno de pruebas lo más parecido al tuyo? Facilitarnos la tarea de reproducir tu entorno hará que haya más gente dispuesta a ayudarte. Pásate por [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Gracias amigo..acabo de editar la pregunta.

Comment: Y serian consecutivas porque no use funciones ni nada..

Comment: Bueno, debes saber que las consultas XHR no tienen por qué resolverse de manera consecutiva. Una vez que has lanzado todas ellas (de manera asíncrona) el resultado (el `success`) puede ejecutarse en cualquier orden. El formato de código dificulta mucho su lectura, deberías acostumbrarte a darle un formato claro. En principio veo que por cada elemento devuelto en la consulta XHR original lanzas una consulta XHR exactamente igual para cada resultado. ¿Para qué?

Comment: Podria hacer una funcion que devuelva las canillas y cargarla en cada combo que desee?

Comment: Siempre es mejor y más eficiente obtener toda la información necesaria en una única petición que en múltiples.